# How Can I peek second set of messages in service bus topic?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm trying to work out how I can further messages from a service bus topic.

I can get the first ~250 messages from a Dead Letter Queue, but when I try to get the next 250, I get the first 250 again.

The Subscription to the Topic I'm targeting has over 60'000 messages in the Dead Letter Queue.

I'm using the `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` NuGet package with version `7.0.1`

```
await using var client = new ServiceBusClient(ConnectionString);
var serviceBusReceiver = client.CreateReceiver(TopicName, SubscriptionName, new ServiceBusReceiverOptions
{
    SubQueue = SubQueue.DeadLetter
});

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i += 250)
{
    var serviceBusReceivedMessages = await serviceBusReceiver.PeekMessagesAsync(250, i);
    foreach (var message in serviceBusReceivedMessages)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message.MessageId);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peaking messages with NServiceBus doesn't work that way. When peaking N messages, you'll get *up-to* N, not *exactly* N. Therefore, what I would suggest is to increase your `fromSequenceNumber` parameter passed into `ServiceBusReceiver.PeekMessagesAsync` by the value of `serviceBusReceivedMessages.Count`.